# Why my dependency is printed twice?

Tags: gradle

I have the following fairly simple `build.gradle` build script:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations { libs }

dependencies {
  libs 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final'
}

configurations.libs.files { println it }
```

When I run it with `gradlew build` (I'm using **Gradle 1.12**, latest at the moment) I get the following:

```
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.hibernate', name='hibernate-core', version='4.3.5.Final', configuration='default'}
DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.hibernate', name='hibernate-core', version='4.3.5.Final', configuration='default'}
```

These seem to be the same dependencies, but I don't get it why there are 2 of them when I have added just a single one.

**Does anyone know why?** Did I do something wrong? Or is there something I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Configuration#files` method expects a *predicate*. (For API details, see `Configuration` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).) If you instead pass it a closure containing a `println` statement, (seemingly) strange things will happen. You probably want something like the following instead:

```
// configurations should only be resolved in 
// the execution phase, so let's declare a task
task printLibs {
    doLast {
        configurations.libs.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, this is part of what I did wrong: should have called `each`. What about those 2 dependencies? Even if `files` gets a predicate, why is it applied to 2 dependencies (that seem the same)? Why two, when I have just one?

Comment: what's the difference between those two since I see that what's printed is identical...

Comment: They can't be identical. With `each`, file paths rather than dependency objects will get printed, and I doubt you'll get two paths.

Comment: Then it means they are different in some way... what's the actual difference?

Comment: One prints the resolved files of the configuration. The other is incorrect API usage and will print an undefined number of dependency objects. If that's not what you see, chances are that you didn't copy my code correctly, or that you are seeing the output of some other code.

Comment: ok, now I get it... I tried: `configurations.libs.dependencies.each { println it }` and it shows just one... looks like that `files` method isn't working the way I thought it would :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining... the Gradle DSL can sometimes be a little hard to follow...